# Changing a function from a loop?

Tags: python, function

First time posting.
I have a school assignment where I am trying to decrypt a password from Ceasar's cipher.
I was given the function to work with. I don't know how to get the opposite value of the encryption key.

Edit, here is my code. I don't know what you need so here is most of it.

```
import csv
import sys

#The password list - We start with it populated for testing purposes
passwords = [["yahoo","XqffoZeo"],["google","CoIushujSetu"]]


#The password file name to store the passwords to
passwordFileName = "samplePasswordFile"

#The encryption key for the caesar cypher
encryptionKey=16

#Caesar Cypher Encryption
def passwordEncrypt (unencryptedMessage, key):

    #We will start with an empty string as our encryptedMessage
    encryptedMessage = ''

    #For each symbol in the unencryptedMessage we will add an encrypted 
    #symbol into the encryptedMessage
    for symbol in unencryptedMessage:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('a'):
                    num += 26

            encryptedMessage += chr(num)
        else:
            encryptedMessage += symbol

    return encryptedMessage

def loadPasswordFile(fileName):

    with open(fileName, newline='') as csvfile:
        passwordreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        passwordList = list(passwordreader)

    return passwordList

def savePasswordFile(passwordList, fileName):

    with open(fileName, 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
        passwordwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        passwordwriter.writerows(passwordList)

if(choice == '2'): #Lookup at password
    print("Which website do you want to lookup the password for?")
    for keyvalue in passwords:
        print(keyvalue[0])
        passwordToLookup = input()
        for keyvalue in passwords:
            website = keyvalue[0]
            password = keyvalue[1]
            if website == passwordToLookup:
                encryptionKey = encryptionKey -16
                passwordEncrypt(password, encryptionKey)
                print(password)
```

I've tried multiple ways and I still can't come to a conclusion.

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: You want to decrypt the `password` that was encrypted with `passwordEncrypt`? If the `encryptionKey` is `16`, maybe `-16` works for the opposite but we would have to see the code of `passwordEncrypt` to know.

Comment: Is that enough information to point me into the right direction?

Comment: As I thought the `passwordEncrypt` can also decrypt just by counting in the opposite direction (negative key value).